# Simulate background: cover; with fixed values?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I mean, is there any way to achieve the same effect as if I used background-size: cover, with fixed values of the background-image?

I tried:

```
<div class="foo"></div>

.foo {
    ...
    background-size: 100vmax 100vmax;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c08eagq8/

But, of course, this won't preserve image's original proportions. Any thoughts?

Comment: i cant understand what you asking :( same effect? vmax? what are you trying to say?

Comment: @Sharky the OP wants to get the `background-size:cover` effect, without using `cover`. As in, it covers the entire element, but retains its ratio.

Comment: why can't you use background-size: cover? @JacobGray, background-size: cover does retain the images ratio, or does the image want to be 100% height and width of container so it does not retain ratio?

Comment: @Dhunt yes, cover retains the ratio :) What I said was they want the same effect as cover gives, without actually using cover. I don't have a clue why they would want to do that, but...

Comment: @JacobGray ah, misinterpreted what you meant.

Comment: @JacobGray smells like looking for a dirty solution to "cover" -pun intended- some other dirty approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. I want to set the background image of an element to 100% of the viewport height, yet cover the full width of the element. The element can have any height, so I cannot use "cover".

Comment: @Deka87 reading your comment, isn't what you exactly describe the "background size cover" supposed to do? still cant understand your problem :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

this is for horizontal images, viceversa for vertical images.

But of course this needs you to know if the image is horizontal or vertical

Here is my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c08eagq8/3/)

Comment: this answer and *something like* in js: `((the_width/the_height)>1)? load_css_for_horizontal:load_css_for_vertical;` and its complete.

Comment: The answer is good, but, as you said, I do not know beforehand  if the image is horizontal or vertical

Comment: @Sharky I was hoping for a css only solution.

Comment: @Deka87 Well, backgroun-size: cover` is your full css solution. I'm afraid there is no other css-only solution to get that effect